# rsync of a renamed folder created duplicated folder (one invisible)

Tags: windows, rsync, filenames

I have a weird problem and I am not sure how to proceed:

I had one folder called `AL18`, which was backed up with rsync some time ago.

In the meanwhile, this folder was renamed to `al18` and a new folder with different contents took the place of `AL18`. Then I did another backup with rsync.

Now if I do `ls` in the backup folder only `AL18` appears. But if I do `ls al18/` or `ls AL18/` they list both the same files, and adding a new file in one,adds a new file in the other.

So i have some kind of duplicity! And my questions are simple: How and why? And what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that where I do the backup, a windows share (mounted with cifs), any file can be written in capital or lower case letters. Thus the confusion!

So beware of windows mounts and equal filenames with different cases